# Actual Focal Length on APS-C cameras

Tags: lens, focal-length, aps-c

I'm aware that actual focal length of a lens on APS-C cameras is longer than what is written on the lens.

My question is, for lenses that are specially designed for APS-C cameras (like a Nikkor DX lens), do they write actual focal length on the lens or it is the focal length if mounted on a full-frame camera?

Comment: Also see [Is the kit lens focal length specified for APS-C or FF?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3338/1943) and [Why does crop factor apply with APS-C lenses, and why aren't these brighter than FF ones at same aperture?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/54800/1943).

Comment: Also, [What is “angle of view” in photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/what-is-angle-of-view-in-photography) should help you with the basic concepts behind this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm aware that actual focal length of a lens on APS-C cameras is longer than what is written on the lens.

Sorry to say this, but whoever told you that was wrong. The actual focal length of a lens on an APS-C camera is exactly<sup>1</sup> what is written on the lens. What you're probably confused about is the fact that the field of view you get from mounting a 50mm lens on an APS-C camera is the same is that of mounting a 75-80mm lens on a full-frame camera (this varies a bit because "APS-C" sized sensors vary a bit between manufacturers). There's a lot of good information about this in our existing question at [Does my crop sensor camera actually turn my lenses into a longer focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/does-my-crop-sensor-camera-actually-turn-my-lenses-into-a-longer-focal-length)

1. Within normal manufacturing tolerances, manufacturers rounding numbers, etc. But that applies equally to all lenses.

Answer (score 0):

The "crop factor" of sensors smaller than full frame is never respected in the specs of lenses. A 50mm EF-S lens has the same focal length as a 50mm EF lens, and will produce the same field-of-view on the same camera.